# Error loading rJava.so when using ReporteRsjars

Tags: r

I am running R 3.5.0 on a Ubuntu 18.04 machine. Some Shiny app I am testing with this new environment uses the ReporteRsjars package and gives the following error message on loading this package:

`Loading required package: ReporteRsjars
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ReporteRsjars’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Warning: Error in : package ‘ReporteRsjars’ could not be loaded`

The file `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rJava/libs/rJava.so`however does exist.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After quite some more trying I found the solution - and realized that I mis-interpreted the error message: The missing library was actually the `libjvm.so` which was not found. A symlink

`ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so /usr/lib`

followed by a `R CMD javareconf`and a removal and re-installation of the `rJava`package did it for me.